# Convert an excel range into image without copy and paste

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a solution were a given excel range can be converted to an image without copy and paste or without putting anything in clipboard.

The reason for this is because the VBA code will be running in the background and the user will continue their regular work.  So when they do any copy and paste activity happens 'oRange.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture' code hits an error.

The tool will run every 60 seconds.

I have checked a lot of web portals to find an answer, but most of them are limited to 'CopyPicture'.  One webpage example given below.

http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-save-excel-range-as-image-using.html

Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, might not directly solve this.  I have created another instance of windows log in and run this Marco at regular intervals in that instance.

This way we have two different clip boards that will not conflict.